# Read specific lines of csv file

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Hllo guys,
so i have a huge CSV file (500K of lines), i want to process the file simultaneously with 4 processes (so each one will read aprox. 100K of lines)
what is the best way to do it using multi proccessing?

what i have up til now:

```
def csv_handler(path, procceses = 5):

    test_arr = []
    with open(path) as fd:
        reader = DictReader(fd)

        for row in reader:
            test_arr.append(row)

    current_line = 0
    equal_length = len(test_arr) / 5

    for i in range(5):
        process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_data, args=(test_arr[current_line: current_line + equal_length],))
        current_line = current_line + equal_length
```

i know it's a bad udea to do that with one reading line, but i don't find another option..
i would be happy to get some ideas to how to do it in a better way!

Comment: I am more-or-less just guessing, but I'd say that the bottleneck in reading a CSV file is file access, so splitting it in multiple processes would only slow it down.

Comment: so what is the best way to read 500K of lines without any bottlenecks?

Comment: @zvone That can really depend. Modern SSD, NVMe are really fast, and if the file is cached then it is memory speed. Last time I wanted I really struggled to get even a C-program to parse and process some stuff at the sequential read speed.

Comment: So.. the best way is to read the whole file at one shot? so i do i parse the file into 100K of lines and send them into a function or so? @FireLancer

Comment: @lollol The biggest problem is that you don't know where the end of 100 000th line is without reading 100 000 lines and then it is already too late. You have to split blindly and then look for the next/previous newline and use that as the splitting point. Then it is relatively easy to distribute that to different processes.

Comment: @FireLancer That makes sense, I guess my guess was wrong ;)

Comment: @zvone what do you mean by splitting bliendly? how do i do that?

Comment: @zvone Having drives that can read a few GB/s a second while processors are only a little per-core faster (especially server cores) than the 7200rpm HDD days honestly really did surprise me in it's difficulty the first time I tried :) Of course, bad file I/O, random access, small buffers, no queue depths, etc. can still slow to a crawl, but reading through say a CSV should be near ideal.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a pretty tricky format to split the reads up with, and other file formats may be more ideal.

The basic problem is that as lines may be different lengths, you can't know where to start reading a particular lines easily to "`fseek`" to it. You would have to scan through the file counting newlines, which is basically, reading it.

But you can get pretty close which sounds like it is enough for your needs. Say for two parts, take the file size, divide that by 2.

- The first part you start at zero, and stop *after* completing the record at `file_size / 2`.
- The second part, you seek to `file_size / 2`, look for the next new line, and start there.

This way while the Python processes won't all get exactly the same amount it will be pretty close, and avoids too much inter-process message passing or multi-threading and with CPython probably the global interpreter lock.

---

Of course all the normal things for optimising either file IO, or Python code still apply (depending on where your bottleneck lies. You *need to measure this*.).

Comment: and how do i read into the file/2? what should i do with the nies im reading? adding them into an array and then send each array into a function with multiproccessing?

Comment: Use the [`file.seek(offset)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) to seek the 2nd, 3rd extra processes to the relevant starting points. Do the actual reading in each process.